# Selecting all object for which not exists value

Tags: mysql, select

I have two tables:
object that has object_id column
and avalues that have object_id (FK for object.object_id) and value_type (for simplicity I ommited other columns).

I want to select all objects that don't have values with specified type. My select looks like this:

```
SELECT object_id FROM object WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT true FROM avalues v WHERE v.value_type = 10 and v.object_id = object_id);
```

is there more effective way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NOT IN` and `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` are slightly more efficient:

```
SELECT  object_id
FROM    object
WHERE   object_id NOT IN
        (
        SELECT object_id
        FROM   avalues v
        WHERE  v.value_type = 10
        )
```

or

```
SELECT  o.object_id
FROM    object o
LEFT JOIN
        avalues v
ON      v.object_id = o.object_id
        AND v.value_type = 10
WHERE   v.object_id IS NULL
```

Make sure that you have an index on `avalues (object_id, value_type)`